# Acessar variável fora de loop for

Tags: python-3.x, loop

Como acesso a variável `cookies` fora do loop?

```
cookies = []
for i in get_cookies(url):
   cookies = '='.join(i) + '; '
print(cookies)
```

Está retornando apenas isso:

`personalization_id="v1_8yKL+7c5RUQ+HHELlnh5dw==";`

Preciso que retorne todos os outros em uma única linha, quando dou `print(i)`, está retornando:

```
('_twitter_sess', 'BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCDzJKCprAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlMDY3NjhlNWQ2NzIwZWIzOWFhOGY4YmNjM2QyZTJlODY6B2lkIiU3OTY2%250AMmM1YjYzYmViYTgxYmZhNDM5OWVjYzJiMzU3Mg%253D%253D--1986635940f2d9bf0f775422f9999122b0279d8c')('ct0', '94d313ad03ce413f521761c16b4bfb63')('guest_id', 'v1%3A155978044447406891')('personalization_id', '"v1_8yKL+7c5RUQ+HHELlnh5dw=="')
```

preciso que fique assim:

`_twitter_sess=BAh...; ct0=123...` assim por diante

Comment: Guilherme não ficou claro sua dúvida poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Se a ideia é concatenar tudo você precisa de fazer `cookies += ` em vez de `cookies =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código:

```
cookies = []
for i in get_cookies(url):
   cookies = '='.join(i) + '; '
print(cookies)
```

Você definiu `cookies` como uma lista, mas quer que o resultado seja uma *string*; dentro do laço de repetição você está sobrescrevendo o valor de `cookies`, ou seja, o valor anterior sempre será perdido. Assim, depois de finalizar o laço, apenas o último cookie estará em `cookies`.

Para corrigir isso você **1)** inicia corretamente a variável `cookies` e **2)** utiliza a concatenação ao invés da atribuição dentro do laço.

```
cookies = ''
for i in get_cookies(url):
   cookies += '='.join(i) + '; '
print(cookies)
```

Mas é Python, você não precisa fazer tudo isso na mão, basta utilizar as ferramentas que a linguagem te proporciona:

```
cookies = ';'.join(f'{name}: {value}' for name, value in get_cookies(url))
```

Comment: Isso funcionou, acabei de fazer outra pergunta parecida com essa, não consegui editar :/, mas isso resolveu cara, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: o código funciona, mas veja que não tem motivo nenhum para ter aquele `for` ali.

Comment: ah - eu que confundi uma coisa aqui. precisa sim :-) (vou apagar os comentários)